# IPCM Macroblock found

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, h.264, jcodec

I try to load an video into an Vectorpublish document.

Everything works find so far. But at frame 150 the Video (huge mp4-file about 56.2 Gibibyte) decoder breaks.

This is the code.

```
package net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.video;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.jcodec.api.FrameGrab;
import org.jcodec.codecs.h264.io.model.Frame;
import org.jcodec.common.io.FileChannelWrapper;
import org.jcodec.common.io.NIOUtils;
import org.jcodec.common.model.Picture;
import org.jcodec.scale.AWTUtil;

import net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.History;
import net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.api.history.Redo;
import net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.api.layer.LayerSelectionListener;
import net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.api.ui.Dialog;
import net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.api.ui.KeyframeSlider;
import net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.api.ui.ToolBar;
import net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.api.ui.VPAbstractAction;
import net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.api.ui.kf.Keyframer;
import net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.api.vpd.DocumentNode;
import net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.api.vpd.VectorPublishNode;
import net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.ui.ImageKey;
import net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.video.hs.AddVideoStep;
import net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.video.hs.data.AddVideoStepData;

@Named
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class LoadVideoButton extends VPAbstractAction implements LayerSelectionListener {
    public LoadVideoButton() {
        super(VideoText.ADD_VIDEO, VideoText.ADD_VIDEO_DESC, true);
    }

    public DocumentNode doc = null;
    @Inject
    public Dialog dlg = null;

    @Inject
    public final KeyframeSlider ks = null;

    @Inject
    public final History h = null;

    @Inject
    public final Redo redo = null;

    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                File video = dlg.showOpenFile("mp4", "MP4 video").getAbsoluteFile();
                try {
                    FileChannelWrapper channel = NIOUtils.readableChannel(video);
                    FrameGrab graber = FrameGrab.createFrameGrab(channel);
                    int count = graber.getVideoTrack().getMeta().getTotalFrames();
                    List<BufferedImage> images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>(count);
                    for (int frameNo = 0; frameNo < count; frameNo++) {
                        System.out.println("load frame " + frameNo);
                        Picture nativeFrame = graber.getNativeFrame();

                        if (nativeFrame instanceof Frame) {
                            Frame frame = (Frame) nativeFrame;
                            BufferedImage bufferedImage = AWTUtil.toBufferedImage(frame);
                            images.add(bufferedImage);
                        }
                    }
                    NIOUtils.closeQuietly(channel);
                    AddVideoStepData data = new AddVideoStepData(images);
                    AddVideoStep step = new AddVideoStep(h, doc.getLastExecutedHistoryStep(), data);
                    redo.actionPerformed(event);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Inject
    private final ToolBar tb = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        setIcons(VideoText.NS, ImageKey.get("add.video"));
        tb.add(this);
    }

    public void notify(Set<VectorPublishNode> arg0) {
        if (arg0.size() == 1 && arg0.iterator().next() instanceof DocumentNode) {
            doc = (DocumentNode) arg0.iterator().next();
        } else {
            doc = null;
        }
        setEnabled(doc != null);
    }
}
```

This is the log:

```
DefaultI8nImageFactory Found: Image for key net.vectorpublish:io/open/small in cache!    (DefaultI8nImageFactory > OpenImpl)
DefaultI8nImageFactory Found: Image for key net.vectorpublish:io/open/large in cache!    (DefaultI8nImageFactory > OpenImpl)
DefaultI8nImageFactory Found: Image for key de.e-nexus:video/add.video/small in cache!   (DefaultI8nImageFactory > LoadVideoButton)
DefaultI8nImageFactory Found: Image for key de.e-nexus:video/add.video/large in cache!   (DefaultI8nImageFactory > LoadVideoButton)
DefaultI8nImageFactory Found: Image for key net.vectorpublish:io/document/small in cache!        (DefaultI8nImageFactory > IOContributions > LanguageController)
DefaultLogger Show dialog: Ask dialog.   (unknown)
LayerSelectionManager Notify: 9 listeners about tree-selection.          (LayerSelectionManager > LayerImpl > NewFile > FilesImpl > FilesImpl > FilesImpl)
AddKeyframe Method in: Check for Add/Modify Keyframe availability. evaluateEnableButton          (AddKeyframe > AddKeyframe > LayerSelectionManager > LayerImpl > NewFile > FilesImpl > FilesImpl > FilesImpl)
AddKeyframe Found: 0 Keyframer and 1 non-Keyframer.      (AddKeyframe > AddKeyframe > LayerSelectionManager > LayerImpl > NewFile > FilesImpl > FilesImpl > FilesImpl)
LayerSelectionManager Notify: 9 listeners about tree-selection.          (LayerSelectionManager > LayerImpl)
AddKeyframe Method in: Check for Add/Modify Keyframe availability. evaluateEnableButton          (AddKeyframe > AddKeyframe > LayerSelectionManager > LayerImpl)
AddKeyframe Found: 0 Keyframer and 0 non-Keyframer.      (AddKeyframe > AddKeyframe > LayerSelectionManager > LayerImpl)
LayerSelectionManager Notify: 9 listeners about tree-selection.          (LayerSelectionManager > LayerImpl)
AddKeyframe Method in: Check for Add/Modify Keyframe availability. evaluateEnableButton          (AddKeyframe > AddKeyframe > LayerSelectionManager > LayerImpl)
AddKeyframe Found: 0 Keyframer and 1 non-Keyframer.      (AddKeyframe > AddKeyframe > LayerSelectionManager > LayerImpl)
load frame 0
load frame 1
load frame 2
load frame ... (cut)
load frame 148
load frame 149
load frame 150
[WARN]  . (:0): IPCM macroblock found. Not tested, may cause unpredictable behavior.
[WARN]  . (:0): IPCM macroblock found. Not tested, may cause unpredictable behavior.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.decode.deblock.DeblockingFilter.calcBsH(DeblockingFilter.java:160)
        at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.decode.deblock.DeblockingFilter.deblockFrame(DeblockingFilter.java:71)
        at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Decoder$FrameDecoder.decodeFrame(H264Decoder.java:156)
        at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Decoder.decodeFrameFromNals(H264Decoder.java:103)
        at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Decoder.decodeFrame(H264Decoder.java:99)
        at org.jcodec.api.specific.AVCMP4Adaptor.decodeFrame(AVCMP4Adaptor.java:68)
        at org.jcodec.api.FrameGrab.getNativeFrame(FrameGrab.java:242)
        at net.vectorpublish.desktop.vp.video.LoadVideoButton$1.run(LoadVideoButton.java:68)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

IPCM macroblocks are unuasual, but completely legal. If your decoder doesn’t support it, use a different decoder, or convert this video first.